# Make part of UIImageView intangible in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, uiimageview

My iPad program have only custom windows, made with `UIImageView`. They can be moved, they have buttons, and they just work fine. In one of that windows, there is a rectangular hole, in order to put a video inside it (like a TV), but it have an irregular format, so the video player (which is an `UIWebView` with a video player inside) must be behind the window.

The problem is: since iOS 6.0, autoplay instructions inside HTML5 aren't accepted, so the user need to click in the video in order to play, which is impossible, because the `UIImageView` is in front of it.

There is a way to make part of the `UIImageView` intangible, so the user can click in the `UIWebView` without problems? There's another solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a class inheriting from UIImageView for this purpose and implement

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

in that function you should check if the point is in the rect where your video is and return NO in that case. You can do that by using

```
CGRectContainsPoint()
```

otherwise return the value of the super implementation

```
return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
```

the touch will be delegated to the underlying view(s) if you return NO

Comment: This is the right answer imho. Another approach can be override the hitTest:withEvent: method and return the view you want to send the touch to.

Comment: He has to check then for the point in rect again and return nil for hitTest:withEvent: in that case because his video view is not a subview of his imageView. hitTest:withEvent: is meant to return a view that is the receiver or a subview of it. returning nil on hitTest:withEvent: will delegate the touch to the underlying view(s).

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I will give it a try in some hours, when I get at home.

Answer (score 0):

```
frontImageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: He wants to make *a part* of the view untouchable, not the entire view :-)